# Delegate Method not being called by the parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, delegates

Im building an app that calls different subviews and lay them over in a main view controller (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyG7S.jpg)

when ever the user clicks a button on the bottom part of the screen (lets call it sliding menu!) the view behind it will disappear and new one will show up.

one of the subviews is Settings , which it have some switches to enable/disable some of the buttons.

in the SettingsViewController.
Ive set a protocol:

```
@protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)hideCountdownView;
-(void)showCountdownView;
@end
```

and the interface contains:

```
@interface SettingsHubViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *enableCountdown;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SettingsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
@end
```

and in the Implementation:

```
- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {
    if (!self.enableCountdown.on) {
        NSLog(@"The view is Hidden");
        [_delegate hideCountdownView];
    } else if (self.enableCountdown.on) {
        NSLog(@"The view is Shown");
        [_delegate showCountdownView];
    }
}
```

You can see i used _delegate to use the show and hide functions, I used NSLog to make sure that Im calling the functions correctly.

in the MainViewController

```
#import "SettingsHubViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController () <SettingsViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SettingsHubViewController * settingsViewController;
```

and the Implementation

@implementation MainViewController

```
-(void)showCountdownView {
    self.slidingMainMenuViewController.countdownView.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"Showing Countdown");
}

-(void)hideCountdownView {
    self.slidingMainMenuViewController.countdownView.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Hiding Countdown");
}

-(void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.settingsViewController.delegate = self;
    self.slidingMainMenuViewController.delegate = self; 
}
```

the problem is that the NSLogs above is not being called at all, can any one help me ?

Thanks

UPDATE: Since i have more that 20 different views that needs to be called, i created this method

```
- (UIView *) getPresentedMenu:(NSString *) menuIdentifer withMenuTag:(int) menuTag withAViewController:(UIViewController*) menuViewController andMenuDelegate:(id) menuDelegate {
    menuViewController = [[UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:Nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:menuIdentifer];
    menuViewController.view.tag = menuTag;
    if (self.viewBeingCalledBySwipe == NO) {
        menuViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, menuViewController.view.frame.size.height, menuViewController.view.frame.size.width, menuViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    } else if (self.isItRightSwipe == YES) {
        menuViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-menuViewController.view.frame.size.width, 0, menuViewController.view.frame.size.width, menuViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    } else if (self.isItRightSwipe == NO) {
        menuViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(menuViewController.view.frame.size.width, 0, menuViewController.view.frame.size.width, menuViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    }

    [self.view addSubview:menuViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:menuViewController];
    [menuViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    UIView *view = menuViewController.view;
    return view;
}
```

So when ever i need a certain view controller, i just call this function

```
self.childView = [self getPresentedMenu:@"Settings" withMenuTag:SETTINGS_TAG withAViewController:self.settingsViewController andMenuDelegate:self.settingsViewController.delegate];
```

but this method is not assigning the delegate

Comment: is `switchAction` actually getting called? Put an `NSLog` at the top or breakpoint inside it to see if it actually gets called. I see that it is an `IBAction`. You most likely forgot to hook up the action in interface builder.

Comment: Yes switchAction is being called because i can see "The View is Hidden" and "The View is Shown" in the console

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `switchAction` and make sure that the delegate is not nil. I suspect it is either not set properly or getting released before it should be.

Comment: YES, The _delegate is a null pointer, how can i fix that ?

Comment: Check the `viewDidLoad` method where the delegates are getting set. Are `settingsViewController` and `slidingMainMenuViewController` nil at that point? If they are, you need to instantiate them before you set their delegates because otherwise you aren't actually doing anything there.

Comment: Well settingsViewController is not equal to null, but the _delegate property is null , i guess i need to fix that, Thank You Very Much :D

Comment: Where have you allocated your settingsViewController?

Comment: Im using the function that i just updated above to call a certain viewController. i guess the problem is that im not instantiating them properly

Answer (score 0):

If settingsViewController is an IBOutlet, you have to add `IBOutlet` to it's declaration and connect it using the storyboard or xib.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet SettingsHubViewController * settingsViewController;
```

But if it's not an Outlet, you have to allocate it before set it's delegate.

```
self.settingsViewController = [[SettingsHubViewController alloc] init];
self.settingsViewController.delegate = self;
```

You should also verify that your `- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender` IBAction is correctly connected in the storyboard or xib.

Comment: Verify that your `- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender` IBAction is correctly connected in the storyboard or xib

Comment: Where do you alloc init your object? can you add this part of code in your question?

Comment: Can you add the code where you allocate your settingsViewController in your question? It would help us.

Comment: i updated the question, i think im doing something wrong in calling the function to view the viewController.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your `SettingsViewController`, make sure that you do it using the storyboard method and not `[[SettingsViewController alloc] init]`.

---

First set a `Storyboard ID` directly in your storyboard view:

[image]

Then use this to `settingsViewController`:

```
self.settingsViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];
```

Replace `MainStoryboard_iPhone` with your Storyboard name.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using that , I can call the view, but the problem is in assigning the delegate correctly, Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user3277090 Could you check the `self.settingsViewController` value before setting the delegate in your `viewDidLoad` and write it here please?

Comment: _settingsViewController SettingsHubViewController * 0x9ab5180 0x09ab5180
UIViewController UIViewController  
_enableCountdown UISwitch * 0x9ab5a30 0x09ab5a30
_delegate id 0x0 0x00000000
_mainView UIView * 0x9ab7720 0x09ab7720

Comment: What does it say if you insert `NSLog(@"%@", self.settingsViewController.delegate)` right after `self.settingsViewController.delegate = self;` ?

Answer (score 0):

// If u are using View controller
SettingsHubViewController *settingVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryBoardIdentifier"];

settingVC.delegate =  self;

// If u are using XIB load the NIB after that set the  settingVC.delegate =  self;

its working for me (I created OverLay view and loaded in main class)